# Sepecific data from table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table and I want to get a specific item from it.

For example the statement :

`"SELECT password FROM "+tableName+" WHERE username='"+username+"'";`

How can I use that statement and get the string value of the password I asked for?

(I was able to get the curser but I couldn't get from it the string value of it)

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String sql ="SELECT password FROM "+tableName+" WHERE username='"+username+"'";
    cursor= db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    String checked = cursor.getString(3);
    if(checked.equals(password)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

The problam is with the line:

```
String checked = cursor.getString(3);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to `moveToFirst` your cursor first. Read any tutorial or introduction to SQL on Android.

Comment: Just to add `cursor.moveToFirst() ` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this 
**cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column name"));**
Best regards

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: Really??? Dont forget to first do somethin like this : `Cursor res= db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        String data[][]=new String[4][5];
        int x=-1;
        while(res.moveToNext()){
            x++;
            data[x][0]= res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("test"));
            data[x][1]= res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("test1"));
            data[x][2]= res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("test2"));
            data[x][3]= res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("test3"));
            data[x][4]= res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("test4"));
        }` This should work, it's working for me :=